# Ruby on Rails, get objects out of contoller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

My update.html.erb:

```
<% @uploads.each do |upload| %>

        <p><%= upload.name %></p>               
        <p class="grey">

    <%= best_in_place upload, :place, type: :select, collection: [ ["Home", "Home"],["Sauna", "Sauna"]]%>  

            </p>    
  <%end%>
```

controller:

```
 def show
      @uploads = Upload.all 
  end
  def update
    @uploads = Upload.all
    @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.update_attributes(params[:upload])
        format.html { redirect_to @upload, notice: 'Upload was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is that I get the error: `undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass` , meaning that my controllers do not pass my object to the variable @uploads. Why do not the do that and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

ps. I could write at the top of my view something like this:

```
<% @uploads=Uploads.all%>
```

But that is not the best idea.
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Make sure your updates.html.erb file is in the proper directory (app/views/uploads) because if it isn't it can throw off the "Rails magic" of convention over configuration. 2. If that's not it, run 'rake routes' at the command line and copy and paste the output in your original question as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @uploads.each do |upload| %>

<%end if @uploads.present? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF your routes are RESTful routes, the update method is a HTTP PUT method and it shouldn't have a template. What you are looking for is a edit action:

```
def edit
    @uploads = Upload.all
end
```

Comment: I didn't get about my routes actually, but when I change my edit action to what you suggested I still get the same error

Comment: well do you have any upload records in your db?

Answer (score 0):

@katja: Referring to your comment.
update is a HTTP PUT request, you cant get a record in that but edit is a get request you can get all records in edit action.

You can add a before_filter callback to your edit action.

```
before_filter :get_all_uploads, only: [:edit]  

def get_all_uploads  
  @uploads = Upload.all  
end
```

And in your edit.html.erb you can do

```
<% @uploads.each do |upload| %>

    <p><%= upload.name %></p>               
    <p class="grey">

<%= best_in_place upload, :place, type: :select, collection: [ ["Home", "Home"],["Sauna", "Sauna"]]%>  

        </p>    
  <% end %>
```

Comment: it still shows me the same error, I changed in to edit.html.erb and edited everything as you suggested but still it doesn't call the edit action